# How to read excel row in meaningful way

Tags: c#, excel

I have an excel with rows like shown in the picture. I need to read each cell like it's a full date.

For example I should read column C, row 1, like 17.01.2018, because column R specifies which month and year we're talking about in the previous columns.

I'm trying for 2 days now to figure out something, but I'm just stuck in C#. I know with Excel we can transpose this to a meaningful table, but I don't know any excel scripting.

[image]

Comment: You say "column S specifies which month and year" but Column S contains "Thu 01" - how does that tell you month and year? Did you mean Column R? Please show some code on how you are reading the Excel workbook.

Comment: @NetMage sorry I said "S", it's the "R" column, you're correct. I found a solution using the GemBox Spreadsheet package. I'll post the code now.

Comment: Can you provide the actual value that is in cell C1 and R1? Are they text, or numbers formatted as date/time, and what values are they?

Answer (score -1):

just an example

```
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet1$]", connection); 
    using(OleDbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
         while(dr.Read())
         {
             var row1Col2 = dr[0];
             Console.WriteLine(row1Col2);
         }
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you're doing with this code snippet, thanks a lot.